# OpenCV object detection of a difficult object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I would like to recognize a certain object on an image and determine the corresponding coordinates.
For this I use OpenCV under Python. The object to find is a cylindrical LED lamp (see picture). The lamp has a certain brightness, a pink hue and by the cylindrical shape the lamp is recognizable on a 2D picture as a triangle.

[image: Lamp]

The lamp should be recognized on a picture of a room. As you can see on the picture, the lamp is unfortunately unevenly illuminated. My attempt to extract the lamp via an HSV threshold was not very successful. The inside of the lamp is white and the border is insufficiently delimited.

Is there a better way to reliably detect the lamp?

I had thought about blurring the image and increasing the contrast so that the lamp would have an even color. Unfortunately, this hasn't worked well so far.

The lamp should be detected afterwards in real time on a live recorded video. The lamp also moves through the room.

I would be very grateful for a tip.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to use a Raspberry Pi with camera. Accordingly, the algorithm must be resource-saving.

Comment: Have you considered using an object detection algorithm, like YOLO? There are implementations baked into OpenCV: https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/

Comment: I've been thinking about it. But I would prefer a variant without Deep Learning for simplicity

Comment: I would argue using yolo is simpler... but I guess that's subjective

Comment: I edited my question. I want to use a Raspberry Pi with camera at best so the algorithm must be resource-saving

Comment: Really you should ask this question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. It's too subjective for SO

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a lightweight pre-trained object detection model like YOLO or SSD with something like a [mobilenet backend](https://github.com/Adamdad/keras-YOLOv3-mobilenet).

There are plenty of guides showing how people have achieved reasonable (5-10 fps) framerates using these models on Raspberry Pis